# How to change game screen in libgdx without memory leak?

Tags: android, libgdx

I am new in game development and I want to know if in changing the screen do I need dispose the objects first of the current screen before going to the new screen?

Comment: Your question is not clear, So explain your issue in proper way.

Comment: I just want to know if I need to dispose the objects first to avoid memory leak...

Comment: http://vk.com/doc176817789_230749542?hash=85cf1772226158299c&dl=e65ede7064ce709078   go through this book I think it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if you want to keep the screen in memory to show it again. You can choose to keep it in memory so it can be shown again without waiting for it to load again, or dispose it and just reload it in the future if you need it.

When disposing a screen, it should call dispose on every object it owns that implements Disposable. Everything that implements Disposable is hanging onto something in native memory that must be disposed of before the Java object reference is lost.

If you dispose of a Screen, make sure you don't accidentally try to start using it again. You should either null out its reference (if you aren't just pointing the reference to some other Screen), or make sure you point the reference to a new instance of the Screen if you want to use it again.